# Get NSData from an NSOutputStream in memory?

Tags: ios, file-io, nsdata, nsoutputstream

I want to use an NSOutputStream to accumulate data, then when finished, create an NSData object with the contents.  I can do it when the output stream is based on a file, as follows:

```
NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *filePath = [tmpDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempfile"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
NSOutputStream *outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];     [outputStream open];

// fill the output stream here

NSData *contents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[outputStream close];
```

I want the 'contents' variable filled without the temp file being created.  Can I do this all in memory?  I don't see API for that in the [NSOutputStream documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the hard to find documentation, first init the output stream with memory, then call the *propertyForKey* method with the key *NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey*.

For your example:

```
NSOutputStream *outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToMemory];
[outputStream open];

// fill the output stream somehow

NSData *contents = [outputStream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];
[outputStream close];
```